# Fact table and Dimension tables

Tags: data-warehouse, fact-table

I was learning online how what is fact table and dimension table , so it advised to practiced with real data set. as a sample I downloaded this excel file. [image]

I want to try star schema, As far as I under stood it can be divided into multiple fact tables , but all tables are different , does it mean it's already a fact table and cannot be divided into dimensions ?
for credits I got dataset from here https://www.kaggle.com/zynicide/wine-reviews

Answer (score 0):

A typical machine learning data consist of measurements or events, which can be interpreted as **a single fact table**.

The numerical attributes (such as `price`or `points`) are the **measurment attributes of the fact table**.

The *factor* (or *time*)  attributes (such as `country`, `province` or `tester_name`) are **foreign keys** to the **dimension tables**.

The *dimensions* are not contained in your data but they can be implicitely reconstructed using `distinct` keys.

Comment: Hi , thank you for your answer, Could you please tell me a little bit more information about reconstructed dimensions using distinct keys , at least one sample, or a link where I can find good explained  information about it